# keeping the data in a form after it has been sent

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a form that you enter data into and it performs a calculation on it and give an answer. what i want to do is for it to keep the data in the form so that you can quickly repost so that you don't have to change all the data. but I cant keep coming up with the error of it not existing, which I suppose is correct until the form has been posted!

```
@{
  var total = 0m;
  var totalMessage = "";


    if (IsPost)
    {
        var age = Request["frmage"].AsInt(0);
        var weight = Request["frmweight"].AsDecimal();
        var SerCre = Request["frmSerCre"].AsDecimal();
        var sexfactor = Request["frmGender"]== "M" ? 1.23m : 1.04m;

        total =Convert.ToDecimal ((((140 - age)*weight)* sexfactor )/SerCre ) ;

        totalMessage =  total.ToString("0.00") + "(ml/min) ";
    }


}
<div class="memberRegistration">
<form method="post">

<p>
    <label class="formLabel">Age:</label> in years
    <input class="formTextField" type="text" name="frmAge" size="3" value="@age"/>
</p>
<p>
    <label class="formLabel">Weight:</label> in Kg (1st = 6.35kg)
    <input class="formTextField" type="text" name="frmWeight" value="@weight"/>
</p>
<p>
    <label class="formLabel">Serum Creatinine:</label> in μmol/L
    <input class="formTextField" type="text" name="frmSerCre" value="@SerCre"/>

</p>
<p>

<label class="fieldLabel">Gender:</label>
    <select name="frmGender" id="select" value="@sexfactor">
        <option value="M">Male</option>
        <option value="F">Female</option>
    </select>

</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Calculate" /></p>
</form>
<p>Calculated creatinine clearance <b>@totalMessage</b></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var age = 0;

    if (IsPost)
    {
        age = Request["frmage"].AsInt(0);

    }

<input class="formTextField" type="text" name="frmAge" size="3" value="@age"/>
```

---

But normally it would be better to use a model to hold your values, then in your controller you pass those values back again to your form

Comment: get the error "A local variable named 'age' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'age', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else" i presume this is because its being defined twice!?

Comment: remove the var from the age variable in your IsPost block

Answer (score 0):

Enable the ViewState of the page and controls and also use aspx control, not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing that i realy understand the Question because the default thing is that the web page keeps it's view state so the data will still be the same after the post back but here's the solution :

you can simply use ASP Controls because it keep it's view state
or you can give each control of them it's value in the C# , you can assign to each control it's value back

Hope I Helped

Comment: on post it seams to be loosing the data in the form, I though it would keep it in hence me trying to put it back into the form block. this issue i'm having is assigning the value back as I think I need some kind of if statement as before the form is posted the value doesn't exist, so causes errors. hope that explains the problem better for you.

Comment: So you need to keep the data after you use response.redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ASP.NET MVC Razor, what you can do is, do not submit the form using `<input type="submit" value="Calculate" />` , instead change it to a simple button like

```
      <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="javascript:Submitform();" />
```

and submit the form using Jquery POST.e.g. like below

```
   function SubmitForm(){
      var formData = $("form").serialize() ;
      var submitUrl = 'yourURL' ;
      $.ajax({
           type : 'POST' , 
           url : submitUrl , 
           data : formData , 
           success : function (data ){ alert ("Request successful") ;}
           error : function (jqXHR, status , errorthrown) { alert ("error Occured");}
        });

   }
```

Comment: and submit the form using Jquery POST. as in <form method="Jquery POST">